# Android Lollipop WebView Facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook-javascript-sdk, android-webview, facebook-login

I have a problem if i implement the Javascript SDK from Facebook in a webview in my app. I want to make a Facebook Connect with the SDK, but this dont work.

When the user isnt connected to Facebook the FB.login() function goes to a blank page. If i logged in in the chrome browser and i call the funtion FB.getLoginStatus(response), i get a curious result:

```
     {authResponse: null, status: "unknown"}
```

This happens only on a Android Lollipop device. On older devices it works correctly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Having same problem. Did you find solution?

Comment: There is a official Bug Report by facebook. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1651116428448693/

Comment: Thanks for answ. It seems that fb tagged bug as long term fixable... So, probably we cannot wait for fix any time soon

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was having the same problem.
I found something you might be able to use and I hope it works.
Check this: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197150/checking-facebook-login-state-in-a-webview-always-returns-unknown)

Basically I guess it's due to third party cookies. Try adding this piece of code before you start the webview:

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mainWebView, true);
}`