# React native app using .setAcceptThirdPartyCookies

Tags: android, cookies, reactjs, webview, native

My login under Webview works well, but the second page doesn't recover the response.status === 'connected' from Facebook SDK.

I found here the solution [Checking Facebook login state in a webView always returns unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197150/checking-facebook-login-state-in-a-webview-always-returns-unknown/28199829#28199829) but my application is not android native.

In a react native application where or how can I verify the following:
`If (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) 
{CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mainWebView, true); }`

Answer (score 1):

I know this comes late but if someone else has problems with cookies inside a webview on android I think this will help.

In order for you to enable third party cookies inside webview, you need to modify some java code.

So you actually need to [build react native from source](https://web.archive.org/web/20180215143257/http://facebook.github.io:80/react-native/docs/android-building-from-source.html) and to modify `react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/webview/ReactWebViewManager.java` file and add the lines you mention where the webview is created (or maybe expose a react webview property that will enable third party cookies).

In my case I added it in `createViewInstance` method right after the webview is initialized above the following lines which enable debugging of the webview:

```
if (ReactBuildConfig.DEBUG && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
  WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
}
```

My code looks like this now:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
  CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
}

if (ReactBuildConfig.DEBUG && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
  WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
}
```